# In order to say "she opened my eyes to something", which construction is stylistically better?

Tags: constructions

> Elle a su m’ouvrir les yeux là-dessus.
>
> Elle a su me faire ouvrir les yeux là-dessus.

The first construction is obviously less complex structure-wise, but I wonder how French speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: 1) |She was able or knew how to open my eyes to something| and 2) |She was able or knew how to make me open my eyes to something. Savoir here is to be able or to know how to do something. Otherwise the French would be: Elle m'a ouvert les yeux

Comment: I would say "she managed to open my eyes"

Answer (score 1):

We would use the first sentence :

> Elle a su m'ouvrir les yeux là-dessus.

You might be afraid that the sentence loses its metaphor by saying it this way, but don't worry it doesn't.

**"Ouvrir les yeux à quelqu'un"** is an idiom commonly used.